# angular2 - How to DOM select a dynamically created element and focus it?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a dynamic HTML list of elements, that all have a specific attribute (for example 'role=option').

**I want to select the first element and give it focus**. In angular 1, it was possible through:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('[role="option"]')).focus()
```

In angular2, I can't find the equivalent way of doing this. All answers seem to involve viewChild and giving a specific `#ref` to an element, but the HTML is created dynamically through `*ngFor`, so every element would end up with the same `#ref` in the loop.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could still use the template reference variable and use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) and the [`first`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#first) property to focus on the first element in the [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList). Try the following

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
  <input #input (change)="templateRefVariable(input.value)"/>
  <br />
</ng-container>
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
  @ViewChildren('input') inputElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  templateRefVariable(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputElems.first.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-abmnfn)